# Vlookup with userform

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, userform

I'm trying to configure Userform research with 3 textboxes, but I can't make it work and don't know why.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
On Error GoTo 1
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A:A"), Me.TextBox1.Value) = 0 Then

 MsgBox "introuvable"
End If
With Me
 .TextBox2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.TextBox1), Feuil1.Range("A:E"), 2, 0)
End With
1
End Sub
```

hoping for your help

thanks

Comment: First off, remove your error handling and run the code again so that you can see what error message you're getting, then let us know what it is. Additionally, you use `Sheets("Feuil1")` with your first range, then you use `Feuil1` as a variable in your `VLOOKUP` - where did you declare `Feuil1`? Should that be `Sheets("Feuil1")`?

Comment: "I can't make it work" - how is it supposed to work?  It's difficult to suggest fixes without knowing what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `WorksheetFunction` and then there will be no run-time error if there's no match:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
    Dim r

    r = Application.VLookup(CLng(Me.TextBox1), Feuil1.Range("A:E"), 2, False)

    Me.TextBox2 = IIf(IsError(r),"Introuvable", r)

End Sub
```